# How to add a DataGridView to a specific location of a Word 2010 template including Grid lines and Column Headers

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I have a DataGridView  with 6 columns, in my C# windows application. 
I want to export this to a specific location of an existing MS Word file.

After completing the export procedure, the grid lines and column headers should be in the document, as appeared in DataGridView in the windows forms application. How I can achieve this?

I was not able to find any online resources directly related to my requirement (especially how to locate this table in a free specified location of an existing document).

I am using C# 2008 and MS Word 2010.

Comment: Do assignments yourself, ask for help after appropriately trying, and showing efforts with possible code as well

Comment: Thanks for the Advice...I did 90% of the program without getting assistance of any one....but this part is too difficult....i have no idea about this...